# Proper DC supply vs batteries

Tags: power-supply, batteries, voltage-regulator, current-limiting, linear-regulator

For the current limiter circuit(using voltage regulator), proper DC supply matches the simulation results. However, when a battery of equal supply voltage is connected, the circuit goes haywire i.e. load current reaches 72mA.
[image]

Comment: Try adding bypass capacitors. For example a 470µF electrolytic plus a 100nF ceramic as close as possible to Vin of the LM317 and ground of the load.

Comment: I'm very confused by your simulation. There is (approximately) 1.25 volts across the 625 ohm resistor. So there should be 2 mA flowing through the resistor. But the simulation meter reads 0 amps on that leg of the circuit (but a bit more than 2 mA on the load). I'm sure I am missing something. Why is the meter showing 0 current?